# Keep transparency when pasting image data

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I am currently trying to make a colision test between images, but I am not understanding some behaviour.

[image: canvas]

I grab with getImageData the image section and try to paste it in another coord. But the transparency does not stay consistent. The imageData object data array tells me that those first pixels do not have opacity cause the alpha channel is set to 0. So why when i paste it back i get those white pixels??

```
function checkColisions(c, s, x, y) {
    let canvasSection = c.ctx.getImageData(x, y, s.width, s.height);

    for (let i=0; i<canvasSection.data.length; i+=4) {
        if (canvasSection.data[i+3] == 255 && s.data[i+3] == 255 ) {
            c.ctx.putImageData(s, x, y);
            return false;
        }
    }

    c.ctx.putImageData(s, x, y);

    return true;
}
```

c is a canvas class with a canvas object in it

s is the image imageData object

x and y are the position where i want to paste

Comment: putImageData will overwrite the actual pixel values, instead of add to them. You may want to look into drawImage instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: Awesome man thx. Place your answer as a solution if you want points. I think this could be done by converting imageData to image and then use it, but in my case your solution works just fine.

Comment: Well don't mind if I do :-) Good to hear it helped!

Answer (score 2):

putImageData will overwrite the actual pixel values, instead of add to them. You may want to look into drawImage instead:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

You should be able to directly reference your earlier canvas as input with a rectangle (sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight) and draw it onto your "destination" canvas (dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)